# add drop down in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am creating my wordpress theme with sub pages and their sub pages also, for this i create my own theme. now I manage these child pages from admin panel to show  header navigation menu dropdown . but its not working , they show him in a line ,not drop down .so how can i show in dropdown in my header part.
my menu code is

```
     <div class="nav">

                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'topmenu', 'walker' => new description_walker(), 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'container' => false)); ?>


            </div>
```

Its show 4 menu.
but I have sub pages in only 2 menu.

so how can i show that?

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring twice ".nav" as a class, the first time you do it in here:

```
      <div class="nav">
```

the second time you declare it in:
            'topmenu', 'walker' => new description_walker(),      'menu_class' => 'nav', 'container' => false)); ?>

so basically you are asigning the class .nav both in the div and in the menu ul, which may create issues depending on yoru css.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin for Dropdown menus: http://shailan.com/wordpress/plugins/dropdown-menu/ - it works perfectly and it has some nice effects you can use too, like a sliding down animation